# Get uid from specific user by find key that contain in his profile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working with React and firebase.
I did a user authentication and, when the user is registered, he is added also to the database.
This is how it looks like in the database:

[image: firebase database]

So I'm trying that, when I'm going to path - "/:user", it will load all the user info from the database.
I have the user name when they are going into. I tried to use filter, but it didn't work for me.

```
const { userId } = useParams(); // giving the path="/:user"
const oneUser = (data) => {
    var users1 = data.val();
    var users = Object.values(users1);
    for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var user = users[i].profile;
        console.log(user); //email: "test@gmail.com" name_profile: "test" etc etc
    }
}

const errData = (err) => {
    console.error(err);
}
var ref = realdb.ref('users/');
ref.on('value', oneUser, errData);
```

and I'm trying to get the specific user that contains the userId in name_profile.

**Update:**

```
const allUsers = (snapshot) => { 
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    snapshot.forEach((userSnapshot) => { 
       let user = userSnapshot.val(); 
       var user1 = user.profile; 
       console.log(user1);
    }) 
} 
var ref = realdb.ref('users/'); 
let query = ref.orderByChild("name_profile").equalTo("test"); 
query.on('value', allUsers, errData);
```

Its working... I deleted the 'profile' child and move everything up and its working. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get all users, you'd do:

```
const allUsers = (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((userSnapshot) => {
        let user = userSnapshot.val();
        var user = user.profile;
        console.log(user); //email: "test@gmail.com" name_profile: "test" etc etc
    }
}
ref.on('value', allUsers, errData);
```

---

If you want to get the profile for the current user, you can address that specific node in the database based on their UID with:

```
const oneUser = (snapshot) => {
    let user = snapshot.val();
    var user = user.profile;
    console.log(user); //email: "test@gmail.com" name_profile: "test" etc etc
}
var ref = realdb.ref('users');
var userRef = ref.child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
userRef.on('value', oneUser, errData);
```

---

If you know the user name (of the value of any other property) for the user you want to load, you can use a **query** to find that user:

```
let query = ref.orderByChild("name_profile").equalTo("test");
query.on('value', allUsers, errData);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, altho its not what i am looking for.
i need to get specific user, not the current user

Comment: How do you know which user you need? If you know a property value, you can use a query. I added an example of tht too.

Comment: its seems like query its what i need, but its keep returning null...
here is what i tried: 
    const allUsers = (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((userSnapshot) => {
            let user = userSnapshot.val();
            var user1 = user.profile;
            console.log(user1); //email: "test@gmail.com" name_profile: "test" etc etc
        })
    }

    var ref = realdb.ref('users/');
    let query = ref.orderByChild("name_profile").equalTo("test");
    query.on('value', allUsers, errData);

Comment: and btw its gave me warning from firebase that i need to use ".indexOn" in rules. i did, but still null :(

Comment: Please don't put code blocks in a comment as they are unreadable. Instead add it to your question as an update (there's an edit link right under it) and then comment here if you want me to have a look.

Comment: Sorry, didnt know that... I update the post with the new code.

Comment: The `console.log(user1);` in your updated code should logging the user data. Are you saying it doesn't do that? Or is the problem elsewhere?\

Comment: I changed the database... i remove the "profile" child and move all up. and now its working. I guess query couldn't go deep data.

Comment: Oh ouch, sorry about that oversight. On your original data structure that should've been `ref.orderByChild("profile/name_profile").equalTo("test")`.

Comment: Oh... nvm i guess :P but nice to know that. Thank you very much for everything :D